# Inline Entity Form - start with first new node open

Tags: version-control, entities

My install is using [Inline Entity Forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) and I would like it so that when a user visits the create node page, the inline entity form starts already visible but with all fields empty and ready to be created (no need to click "Add Node").

I would like to implement either a module or tpl  file in my theme to achieve this. Please can you advise on how to go about it.

I've used this patch https://www.drupal.org/node/2225675 but it only works when editing existing content.

Answer (score 2):

I read the codes in the inline_entity_form.module, and found the inline_entity_form_single is always displaying a form, so i copied its code to my module and it works:

```
function YOURMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  $field = $context['field'];
  if (isset($field['field_name']) && ('FIELD_NAME' == $field['field_name'])) {
    if (empty($element['form']) && empty($element['entities'][0])) {
      $element['actions'] = array();
      $instance = $context['instance'];
      $settings = inline_entity_form_settings($field, $instance);
      $controller = inline_entity_form_get_controller($instance);

      $parents = array_merge($element['#field_parents'], array($element['#field_name'], $element['#language']));
      $parent_langcode = entity_language($element['#entity_type'], $element['#entity']);

      $ief_id = $element['#ief_id'];

      $element['form'] = array (
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#op' => 'add',
        '#parents' => array_merge($parents, array ('form')),
        '#entity_type' => $settings['entity_type'],
        '#parent_language' => $parent_langcode,
        '#ief_id' => $ief_id,
      );
      $bundle = reset($settings['bundles']);

      $form_state['inline_entity_form'][$ief_id]['form settings'] = array (
        'bundle' => $bundle,
      );

      $element['form'] = inline_entity_form_entity_form($controller, $element['form'], $form_state);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for the reply. I've used this code in an existing module I have and am not seeing any change (I made sure to change the function name for my module). I also tried changing FIELD_NAME to my fields name after it didn't work. However, no luck.. I perhaps should have mentioned that I am using the "Multiple Values" widget. Was there anything else you did to get this to work?

Comment: Hi, i was using multiple values too. can you remove "&& empty($element['entities'][0])", clear the caches and try again? The codes I pasted above was just to insert a form for the current element if there is no form at all and no entities.

Comment: I'm sure i must be doing something wrong as still no luck. I've even made a new install with only the required modules. I don't seem to be getting past this line : if (isset($field['field_name']) && ('FIELD_NAME' == $field['field_name'])) {

Comment: I saw your latest comment, good to see it working! Thank you for correcting me. yes, $field = $context['field']; should be put in the beginning.. I mistakenly copied it inside "if" statement from my codes because i did a lot of other things previous from this part.

Answer (score 2):

Once again thanks for your help on this user1455180. I managed to get it working by adding

```
$field = $context['field'];
```

to the beginning of the function you gave me and inserting the name of the field acting as the entity reference in the place of "FIELD_NAME".

```
function YOURMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
$field = $context['field'];
  if (isset($field['field_name']) && ('FIELD_NAME' == $field['field_name'])) {
    if (empty($element['form']) && empty($element['entities'][0])) {
      $element['actions'] = array();
      $field = $context['field'];
      $instance = $context['instance'];
      $settings = inline_entity_form_settings($field, $instance);
      $controller = inline_entity_form_get_controller($instance);

      $parents = array_merge($element['#field_parents'], array($element['#field_name'], $element['#language']));
      $parent_langcode = entity_language($element['#entity_type'], $element['#entity']);

      $ief_id = $element['#ief_id'];

      $element['form'] = array (
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#op' => 'add',
        '#parents' => array_merge($parents, array ('form')),
        '#entity_type' => $settings['entity_type'],
        '#parent_language' => $parent_langcode,
        '#ief_id' => $ief_id,
      );
      $bundle = reset($settings['bundles']);

      $form_state['inline_entity_form'][$ief_id]['form settings'] = array (
        'bundle' => $bundle,
      );

      $element['form'] = inline_entity_form_entity_form($controller, $element['form'], $form_state);
    }
  }
}
```